# ld: framework not found FirebaseAnalytics after upgrading to Xcode 8

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I know there are many related questions about "framework not found FirebaseAnalytics". I have spent time on these related questions and tried the solutions suggested by others but in vain. So I have to ask again there and hope anyone can help me.

My problem is that i'm able to use Firebase SDK(IOS) installing by CocoaPods since Xcode 7. However once I upgraded to Xcode 8.1, I cannot compile my project anymore. It keeps showing the error:

> ld: framework not found FirebaseAnalytics clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Only when I remove the firebase in the pods can I build the project successfully. Also, it comes to my nightmare that i'm unable to install google analytic SDK because the same error message comes again.I think it is because google now combines the firebase in their SDK.

Here is what I tried from the results I found from other posts in Stack-overflow.

1. Open the workspace rather than xcode project
2. Adding $(inherited) in framework search path
3. Remove the CocoaPods project from xcode and re-install again
4. Update the Xcode's CocoaPods project
5. Adding use use_frameworks!, this will create error of #import"XXX" and #import not found
6. Delete red framework in Linker Binary with Libraries

My Xcode version is Version 8.1

Here is my pod setting:

```
platform :ios, '8.1'
def testing_pods
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'AWSMobileAnalytics', '~> 2.4.1'
pod 'AWSSNS', '~> 2.4.1'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
target 'project' do
testing_pods
  target 'project_test' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
target 'project_Dev' do
testing_pods
end
```

Hope someone can help me otherwise I have to migrate this old project to a new one.

Comment: Can you try removing the whole Pods folder, Podfile.lock and the xcworkspace, and call pod install again? I tried the latest pod with XCode 8.1 and it is still working.

Comment: Thank you for your response Alex, i did it, i use the pod deintegrate
$ pod clean $ rm Podfile commend to clean up everything. Some of my friend said they are still working but mine ain't. So sad. I think there must be something that is set wrongly in my target file in Xcode